# Button onClick in MUI Datagrid invoked without clicking

Tags: button, material-ui, datagrid, onclick

I implemented a button inside the MUI v5 Datagrid. Based on the official sample https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/columns/#render-cell , I added the onClick in the Button.

The onClick function was called when the cell was rendered for the first time instead of clicking event.

```
const downloadSearchResult = (params) => {
  const link = document.createElement("a");
  link.download = "download.txt"
  link.href = "./download.txt";
  link.click();
}

const notes = [
  {id: 1, Search_result: "download.txt" },
  {id: 2, Search_result: "pending" },
  {id: 3, Search_result: "pending" },
]

export default function Notes() {
  var show
  const columns: GridColDef [] = [
    { field: 'Search_result', headerName: 'Search result', width: 150,
      renderCell: (params) => (
        <strong>
          {show = (params.value == "Pending")}
          {show && params.value}
          {{!show && 
            <Button 
              variant="contained" size="small"
              onClick={downloadSearchResult(params)}
            >
              Download
            </Button>}}
        </strong>
      )
    },
  ];
  
  return (
    <Container>
      <div>
        <DataGrid rows={notes} columns={columns} />
      </div>      
    </Container>
  )
}
```

onClick function in Call Stack:

[image: onClick function in Call Stack]

Button in MUI v5 Datagrid:

[image: Button in MUI v5 Datagrid]

Answer (score 1):

try

```
  <Button 
          variant="contained" size="small"
          onClick={()=>downloadSearchResult(params)}
        >
```

Comment: You are right. I missed ()=>

Comment: I encountered the similar issue in case of using getActions function. But the above answer resolved. Thank you. The sample code in the official reference misses "() =>".